# Pictures behaving very strangely

Tags: html, css

My buddy had a problem with a website for a school project. He wanted to make a small gallery.

The first 5 pictures worked as intentional:
[image]
but then they showed up like that:
[image]
We tested all sorts of stuff for an hour. We tried to put the bottom 3 ones in another `div` block with `class="bilder"` but it was the same. We also tried putting the pictures in a different order to see if it has something to do with the pictures themselves but also the same result.

```css
div.wrapper {
    font-family: Calibri;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    color: #F99F00;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

li {
    float: left;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 120%
}

li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: green;
}

.active {
    backround-color: green;
}

li.selected  a {
    color: green;
    display: block;
}


#tct  {
    
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    padding: 1%;
    color: #F99F00;
    font-size: 200%;
}



div.bilder img {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 18%;    
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</title>
    <link href="../css/waffenliste.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="pictures/csgotab.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h1>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive<h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="waffenliste.html">Waffenliste</a></li>
                <li><a href="spray.html">Spray Patterns</a></a></li>
                <li><a href="ueber.html">Über</a></a></li>
                <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tct">
            <p>Kaufbar f&uuml;r: T und CT</p>
        </div>
        <div id="t">
            <p>Kaufbar f&uuml;r: Terroristen</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ct">
            <p>Kaufbar f&uuml;r: Antiterroreinheit</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bilder">
        <img id="awp" src="pictures/awp.PNG">
        <img id="scout" src="pictures/scout.PNG">
        <img id="dual" src="pictures/dual.PNG">
        <img id="p250" src="pictures/p250.PNG">
        <img id="deagle" src="pictures/deagle.PNG">
        <img id="nova" src="pictures/nova.PNG">
        <img id="negev" src="pictures/negev.PNG">
        <img id="m249" src="pictures/M249.PNG">
        </div>
        
</div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks ok in your snippet, what's the problem?

Comment: It can't reproduce the problem

Comment: fix your title to **better** describe the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use following css :

```
div.bilder {
    font-size: 0px;
}
div.bilder img {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 18%;    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following html and css structure,

```css
section #imageGallery li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
 list-style: none;
}

section #imageGallery li div {
 width: 280px;
 height: 290px;
 color: black;
}



 #imageGallery .one {
 background-image: url(/Images1.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#f9f8f5;
}
#imageGallery .two {
 background-image: url(/Images2.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#f9f8f5;
}
#imageGallery .three {
 background-image: url(/Images3.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#f9f8f5;
}
#imageGallery .four {
 background-image: url(/Images4.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#f9f8f5;
}
#imageGallery .five {
background-image: url(/Images5.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#f9f8f5;
}
```

```html
<section>
            <ul id="imageGallery">
                
                <li>
                        <div class="Image one">
                          
                        </div>
                </li>
               <li>
                        <div class="Image two">
                          
                        </div>
                </li>
               <li>
                        <div class="Image three">
                          
                        </div>
                </li>
               <li>
                        <div class="Image four">
                          
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <div class="Image five">
                          
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you float all images. You shoudnt use floats to dispaly images in the line. Display `inline-block` is enough.

If you wish to stick with floating use `clearfix` after end of line.

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that doesnt fix it sadly. If we use clearfix we get the exact same result. If we use inline-block the lower 3 inages don't behave like that anymore but there are never 5 pictures in a row and there is a lot of space on the right side [link](https://gyazo.com/7519ceae63bb9831a8347a16c2842a7b)